Render mathjax after fetching latex math code from database (Supabase)
I am using React 18.2.0, better-react-mathjax 2.0.3 and have latex math code in supabase, and am unable to render it after fetching the data from supabase,
fetch data :
  useEffect(() => {
    getQuestions();
  }, []);

  async function getQuestions() {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.from("questions").select("*").limit(20)
      if (error) throw error;
      if (data != null) {setQuest(data);}
    } catch (error) {}
  }


MathJax renders the code which is static but not the code form supabase
<MathJaxContext
            config={config}
            src={"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js"}
          >
            <div className="App">
              <MathJax inline>
                {/* {"$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}$"} */}
              </MathJax>
              <br />
              <MathJax inline dynamic >{newtag}</MathJax>
              <MathJax inline dynamic >{latex}</MathJax>
            </div>
          </MathJaxContext>

newtag being the fetched data and latex being the static data

Does the code from the call contain Mathjax delimiters?

@fast-reflexes dont know what that is, sorry

Mathjax content needs to be wrapped in special symbols, for example $$ or [ and ], are you sure the data newtag and latex are wrapped in that?
